# How to slow the simulation speed to real time passage by the second?

Tags: simulink

I am simulating a train. The simulation runs for infinitely long. I give the train a force, and it moves. I want to show a real-time graph of the distance that the train has traveled. The x-axis is going by 1. But the unit is definitely not second. I know this because I set the x-axis to span from 0 to 60, the graph took up the horizontal span in less than 60 seconds. I only want the graph to update every second. How do I do that?

This is my model:
[image]

I am using Dash Scope:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph *is* showing seconds - seconds of simulation time, not second of wall-clock time.

If you want to artificially slow it down then you have several options, including making the simulation time steps very small, or adding something to the model to `pause` it while wall-clock time catches up with simulation time.  One way of doing this to write an S-function, such as [Real-Time Pacer for Simulink](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29107-real-time-pacer-for-simulink)